# sh: 1: node: Permission denied, install angular on WSL

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I try to install angular on WSL2, I have node version `17.3.1` and npm version `8.3.0` installed.
When I type the command `npm install -g @angular/cli` I get this error:

> npm ERR! code 127
>
> npm ERR! path
> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v17.3.1/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
>
> npm ERR! command failed
>
> npm ERR! command sh -c node ./bin/postinstall/script.js
>
> npm ERR! sh: 1: node: Permission denied
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-01-18T09_06_05_078Z-debug-0.log

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you able to install other packages globally?

Comment: I would suggest `sudo`.

Comment: Yes, it allows me to install other packages globally.

I can't use sudo:
~sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
sudo: npm: command not found

Comment: What doest it return when you type `node -v` in terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run with sudo npm. On Ubuntu, you need to run with root permission. It depends on how you install node.

Try clean your npm cache before

```
npm cache clean
```

or

```
npm cache verify
```

Then:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Comment: Didn't work:  
  
  

npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3 --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root  
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path /root/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node ./bin/postinstall/script.js
npm ERR! sh: 1: node: Permission denied

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-01-19T11_42_03_287Z-debug-0.log

Comment: `npm cache verify` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by uninstalling the WSL and reinstalling it, it gave me many chained errors and I opted for the most drastic way, thanks to all.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with ubuntu 20.04 WSL.

After WSL installation close the terminal and try again.

You might not have permission for writing on npm packages.

Try again installing with `sudo npm install -g <package-name>`